# FBX SDK accessing custom attributes

Tags: c++, maya, autodesk, fbx

I have an FBX file that has had custom attributes added in maya.
Using the FBX SDK, I am trying to load the mesh and retrieve these attributes.

I have:

```
FbxNode* lRootNode = lScene->GetRootNode();
    if (lRootNode) {
        for (int i = 0; i < lRootNode->GetChildCount(); i++)
        {
            FbxProperty p = lRootNode->GetChild(i)->FindProperty("UDPMAYA", false);
            if (!p.IsValid())
                std::cout << "found prop" << std::endl;


            PrintNode(lRootNode->GetChild(i));
        }
    }
```

"UDPMAYA" Could be wrong, i extrapolated from a "UDP3DSMAX" example that I found...

I can't find anything in the docs that explains this, how do I get custom attributes from maya into the fbx sdk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
#define PROPERTY "attribute_name"

FbxMesh* pMesh = (FbxMesh*)pFbxChildNode->GetNodeAttribute();

            FbxProperty p = pFbxChildNode->FindProperty(PROPERTY, false);
            if (p.IsValid())
            {
                std::string nodeName = p.GetName();

                std::cout << "found property: " << nodeName <<std::endl;

            }
```